# conditions for LU on a $2 \times 2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have
$$A=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
I want to do LU factorization on it, so I need to find the elementary matrix $E$ such that $EA=U$ and thus $L=E^{-1}$.  So I know I need the row operation $aR_2-cR_1\rightarrow R_2$, but how do I represent $E$ with this row operation?  I know that if it were just $R_2-cR_1\rightarrow R_2$ the elementary matrix would be 
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        -c & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
How do I get the $a$ involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$aR_2-cR_1\rightarrow R_2$ is not an elementary operation, but the result of two consecutive row operations.  First, we set $aR_2 \to R_2$, then, we set $R_2 - cR_1 \to R_2$.  So, we would have the product of two elementary matrices, namely
$$
E_2 E_1 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
-c&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & a
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
-c & a
\end{bmatrix}
$$